# Call R script from Fortran

Tags: r, fortran90

I am doing an heavy weather simulation in Fortran 90. I would like to call a script in R in order to perform some complicated data analysis. The only way that i found is to write inside a file the data and then calling the system function from Fortan

```
  call system('R CMD BATCH script.r outcome.out')
```

and read the outcomes of the analysis from Fortran in outcome.out. This present some problems in order to manage the file outcome.out when the simulation give bogus numbers.
Does exists a more elegant way to call R from Fortran?

Comment: What kind of problems exactly? 'Some problems' is a but vague.

Comment: in case of error i have some difficult on manage the file of output of R.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not calling R from Fortran, but turning this around. I regularly call Fortran models (executables) from R, and then picking up the results in R. Using R as a means to control the model enables one to e.g. run them in parallel.

Most of the time I actually use a system where the models run in Fortran, the model is run using Python, and I use R for the post-processing.